# Javascript works in html but won't work in .js file

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and have a bit of code that works when included directly in my html file, but when I try and put it into the .js file I am building for my website, it stops working.

Is the "$" being in the .js file causing the problem?

How do I re-write this code so that it can be used in my JS file?

```
<div id="section1" class="dropSection"> 
  <a class="edit top-right">Option 1</a>
  <div class="childSection">
     <div class="splash">item 1</div>
     <div class="splash">item 2</div>
     <div class="splash">item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

   <script>
   $('body').click(function() {
      $('div.childSection').hide();
        });
      $(".dropSection a").click(function(event) {
          var parent = $(this).parent();
          parent.toggleClass("selected");
          parent.find("div.childSection").toggle();
          parent.find("section-content").toggle();
          event.stopPropagation();
        });
  </script>
```

EDIT: In the  section I have a working script reference to jquery-3.6.1.min.js as well as my personal .js file (which does have other working script in it - they just don't used the $ format)

Comment: Please show your HTML so that the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Where do you include your jquery script file? Inside the HTML or the .js file? It should be in the HTML file.

Comment: Also, if you're new to javascript, I wouldn't suggest starting with a framework, especially not JQuery because vanilla javascript have the same features nowadays, just expressed differently.

Comment: What errors do you see in your browser's console?

Comment: And do you actually include that on a page or trying to use Node.js or some other non-browser JavaScript engine?

Comment: The `$` could be a sign that you're using jQuery. Check your *.html for all the Javascript files it's using, to see where it's mentioned (if anywhere). If you want to use the block of code you posted in an external JS file, that JS file needs to be included after your jQuery.

Comment: I have edited it to show my html as well as note that I have 2 working script tags in my <head> section that correctly reference jquery-3.6.1.min.js as well as my working .js file. Everything else in my .js file works, just not this specific code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "$" being in the .js file is not causing the problem. "$" symbol is being used as a shorthand for the jQuery library which also you need to import in your .html file in `<head>` section.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You need to wrap your js code in `$(document).ready(function($)`, because it ensures that the code inside the function only runs after the DOM is fully loaded and ready. So, your finaly `script.js` file will be somethig like this. Also you need to import `script.js` in your html file.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("body").click(function () {
        $("div.childSection").hide();
    });
    $(".dropSection a").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        parent.toggleClass("selected");
        parent.find("div.childSection").toggle();
        parent.find("section-content").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't need `.ready` just add `defer` to the script tag or place it at the end of the body

Comment: Thanks jonu29! That little "wrap" was the piece of the puzzle I was missing!

Comment: @jonu29 could you tell me - does the $(document).ready(function ($) { need to be at the front of each section of code, or is it something that I can put at the start of the .js file and close out at the end, applying it to everything between?

Comment: @JMM yes, wrap all your js code with that. From start to the end of file.